# Context with filtering for daterange is not working

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I am having a view that is working and properly returning results as long as I am not filtering for dates. As soon as I start to add a filter e.g. `booking_time__range = (start_date, end_date)` **no results are returned in my template**. I have no tried to find the error by myself for several days, now I need the wisdom of the crowd.

My Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from users.models import Account
from organization.models import Organization, Office


class Booking(models.Model):
    LOCATION_OPTIONS = (
            ('H', 'Home Office'),
            ('O', 'Office'),
            ('N', 'Not indicated'),
    )
    account             = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization        = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    office              = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booking_time        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    location            = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOCATION_OPTIONS)
    class Meta:
            unique_together = ('account', 'booking_time',)
```

My View:

```
def overview_view(request):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        start_date = None
        end_date = None
        if request.is_ajax():
            booking_times = request.GET.get('day')
            start_date = datetime.strptime(booking_times, "%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=4)
            start_date = start_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
            end_date = end_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        context['bookings']=Booking.objects.filter( Q(organization_id=request.user.organization_id), Q(booking_time__range = (start_date, end_date))
        context['office'] = Office.objects.filter(organization_id__exact=request.user.organization_id)
       
        return render(request, 'overview/overview.html', context)
   return render(request, 'overview/overview.html', context)
```

Both `start_date` and `end_date` are datetime.datetime format. As soon as I remove `Q(booking_time__range = (start_date, end_date)` results will show. But I really need this filter.

My template:

```
    <small>{{ office.office_name }}</small>
    {% for booking in bookings %}
        <div class="client-item">
            <div class="client-text">
                <p class="name">{{ booking.account.first_name }} {{ booking.account.last_name }}</p>
                {% if booking.get_location_display == 'House' %}
                    <p class="sub-title"> {{ booking.get_location_display }}</p>
                {% elif booking.get_location_display == 'Home' %}
                    <p class="sub-title"> {{ booking.get_location_display }}</p>
                {% else %}
                    <p class="sub-title"> {{ booking.get_location_display }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This might be obvious, but have you checked that there are any objects which match your search criteria via the shell for example?

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida-Domingues thanks for the hint... yes I did there are 2 objects and without the filter there are like 10... so it is super weird